# How to update multiple Documents in different Collections a Firestore document

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a messaging app, you create an account with email and password using Firebase this also saves your details in a collection called "appUsers" once you gain access to the app you can choose if you would like to add a profile image,
this works fine and the url of the image is added to "appUsers" which holds all users that have signed upto the app

The second part is when a user wants to save a new contact, they enter a name for the new contact and an email my function checks if there is a user with that email if there is then that selected user's details will be saved into a new collection which is called "myContacts" that all works fine,

My problem is when you change your profile image it updates it in "appUsers" but I don't know how to update that new image url in every collection that my details are saved in
Does anyone know how this can be solved ??

```
// checks if user exists, if they do save them into your own list
static func addContact(email: String, names : String, userUid : String ,com : @escaping () -> ()) {
    guard let currentEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else {return}
    let refrence = Firestore.firestore().collection("appUsers")
    
    refrence.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, Error) in
        if let er = Error {
            print(er)
        } else {
            guard  let snap  = snapshot else {return}
            
            for snap in snap.documents {
                let data = snap.data()
                
                let myContacts = db.collection("contacts_for\(currentEmail)").document().collection("details")
                myContacts.addDocument(data: data).updateData(["names" : names])
                
            }
        }
    }
}

// This function is called if you wish to update your profile image and update the collection which holds all users
static func updateimageUrl(data: Data, currentUid : String, completion : @escaping () -> ()) {
    let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "profileImage\(currentUid)")
    
    imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (meta , error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        imageRef.downloadURL { (URL, Error) in
            
            guard let url = URL?.absoluteString else {return}
            let refrence = db.collection("appUsers").document(currentUid)
            
            refrence.setData(["profileImage" : url], merge: true) { (Error) in
                if let er = error {
                    print(er)
                } else {
                    completion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to iOS and have not ever used Firestore before so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What you're looking for is called a batch write https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update multiple documents, but you don't know what they are, you will have to:

1. Query each of the collections for the documents (using perhaps the old URL you want to change
2. Iterate the result set from each query
3. Update each document individually to contain the new value

If this task is too cumbersome, you might want to consider **not** duplicating the data as you are now.  It's a tradeoff - either perform additional queries to read the from a single document whenever it's needed, or perform multiple updates to find each duplicate when it has to change.